# Get pipes values dynamically in CF7

Tags: php, wordpress, contact-form-7

I'm using **WPCF7_Pipes** class to generate dynamic fields on a 'pipes' *Contact Form 7* select, but i need catch the before and after pipe values.

This is my code:

```
function select_country_cf7 ( $scanned_tag, $replace ) {  

    if ( $scanned_tag['name'] != 'country')  
        return $scanned_tag;
        // end if

    $rows = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'country' );

    if ( ! $rows )  
        return $scanned_tag;
        // end if

    foreach ( $rows as $row ) {
        foreach ( $row as $country ) {
            if($country == 'USA'){
                $mail = 'myfirstmail@my_mail.com';
                } // end if
            else {
                $mail = 'mysecondmail@my_mail.com';
            } // end else
            $scanned_tag['raw_values'][] = $country . '|' . $mail;
        } // end foreach
    } // end foreach

    $pipes = new WPCF7_Pipes($scanned_tag['raw_values']);

    $scanned_tag['values'] = $pipes->collect_befores();
    $scanned_tag['pipes'] = $pipes;

    return $scanned_tag;  
}  

add_filter( 'wpcf7_form_tag', 'select_country_cf7', 10, 2);
```

How i say, the form looks good, but when i try to catch the option value through a *WPCF7_Submission* instance, just get the country but i need to get the mail too.

Comment: use `_raw_country` to catch the country.

Comment: Hi Kaperto, i try this as cf7 help indicates, but doesn't work

Comment: where do you need the value ? edit your question to show us the code you have tested.

Comment: I need the mail value in front end to send an email, but just can get the country. If i use [_raw_contry] don't catch data

Comment: [you can send a second e-mail defined in the tab "mail"](https://contactform7.com/setting-up-mail/)

Comment: I've resolved. There was missing an label data:
`
$scanned_tag['labels'] = $pipes->collect_befores(); // this is the html info for each option
$scanned_tag['pipes'] = $pipes; // this is separator
$scanned_tag['values'] = $pipes->collect_afters(); // this is the value for each option
`
Thanks for all

Answer (score -1):

I've resolved. There was missing an label data:

`$scanned_tag['labels'] = $pipes->collect_befores(); // this is the html info for each option
$scanned_tag['pipes'] = $pipes; // this is separator
$scanned_tag['values'] = $pipes->collect_afters(); // this is the value for each option`

Comment: can you edit your answer to explain where you catch the e-mail address ?